# How does Trip escape from Ehrehin and Valdore?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, star-trek-eu

In the novel *[The Good That Men Do](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Good_That_Men_Do)*, while on the ship with Ehrehin, one moment Trip is passing out or dying and Valdores forces are closing in, and the next moment he's on Earth and he doesn't mention anything about how he got there.

How did he escape?

Comment: It's revealed in the final episode of Enterprise that the entire show took place on the Holodeck, so the answer is, that was just the plot of the game Riker and Troi were playing.

Comment: @Gaius You're misinterpreting that episode. The entire series didn't take place on the holodeck, just the events of the last episode. All other episodes were played out in "real time" so to speak.

Comment: Also, I take your comment about "the game Riker and Troi were playing" to mean that you think the entire series was revealed to be a fictional story within the Star Trek universe which also isn't true. The events Troi and Riker were replaying were historical, not fictional.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in Chapter 52 of the novel.

> After Doctor Ehrehin stunned Trip by shocking him, the Doctor left the ship they were traveling in via escape pod, so that he could rejoin his Romulan compatriots.  Prior to leaving, he programmed the ship's autopilot to re-enter warp after the escape pod was jettisoned, so that Trip could get away.

I found the sudden explained jump in the story puzzling as well.  But, the snarky comments by the characters about the events of the last episode made it all worthwhile.